# Explain meaning of keep function

Tags: functional-programming

Can someone explain meaning and difference of `keep` function from simple `map(array, fun)`

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var even = function (x) { return x % 2 === 0; };

array.map(even);
```

[Description of keep function in Closure docs](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/keep)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this example from the docs you linked:

```
user> (keep #(if (odd? %) %) (range 10))
(1 3 5 7 9)
user> (map #(if (odd? %) %) (range 10))
(nil 1 nil 3 nil 5 nil 7 nil 9)
```

As you can see `keep` does not include `nil` values in the resulting list - `map` does.

Comment: Well I have seen these examples, but the usage pattern still not obvious to me. So it literally just keeps false values as opposite to `filter`? Could you elaborate when `keep` is useful? Seems that this should be convenient pattern if it has its implementation in library.

Comment: @dig It's useful if you have a function that might return `nil` and you want to map that function over a list while ignoring the `nil` values. And no the fact that it keeps false values is not what distinguishes it from filter. `filter` returns a list containing the result of the original values - `keep` returns the results of applying the function. So `keep` is a lot closer to `map` than it is to `filter`. Basically it's `map` followed by a call to `filter` that filters out `nil`s. Except that it does it in one pass.

Comment: thanks, now I see reason to use it, but still wondering why it is named `keep` when it actually throws away nils :)